# Parse Bytes Into Struct Attribute (int16_t) In C

Tags: c, parsing, byte, uint

I am trying to parse these bytes:

```
00000000: 4353 4333 3630 4653 >0200< >0000 1900< 0000
```

Into `uint16_t` and `uint32_t` struct attributes respectively.

The struct at hand:

```
typedef struct __packed {
uint8_t fs_id [8];
uint16_t block_size;
uint32_t file_system_block_count;
uint32_t fat_start_block;
//and so on
```

Taking inspiration from [Selbie's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71598252/16249654) I've written:

```
read(file_descriptor, &blk.fs_id, sizeof(blk.fs_id));
read(file_descriptor, &blk.block_size, sizeof(blk.block_size));
read(file_descriptor, &blk.file_system_block_count, sizeof(blk.file_system_block_count));
// and so on for additional attributes.
```

Unfortunately, upon debugging `block_size` is only holding the value "2" when it is supposed to be holding `uint16_t 512`. Similarly, `file_system_block_count` is holding "1638400" when it should be holding "6400" :(

How do I get the `read()` function to include the "00" after the "02" and therefore read it as 512? I'd imagine it may require `memcpy()`?

Comment: Reading binary data isn't portable, because of different byte orderings.

Comment: Your file is in big-endian format, but your CPU is little-endian.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. This will be running exclusively on Intel's architecture. Ahhh thanks for the clarification

Comment: If you use the same architecture to write and read the file, you should get the expected results. So the question is why it was written as `0200` instad of `0002` if you exclusively use Intel.

Comment: @Barmar I'm compiling using WSL(ubuntu), I'd imagine that's my issue?

Comment: It shouldn't matter. If both the reader and writer are compiled with the same compiler, they should be consistent.

Comment: @Barmar are you aware of how to make the conversion to big-endian?

Comment: Use `htons()` and `htonl()` for 16-bit and 32-bit numbers, respectively.

Comment: @Barmar thank you so much you are amazing. Have a great day of coding and may the force be with you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @barmar a simple call to `htons()` and `htonl()` for 16-bit and 32-bit respectivley is required.

```
memcpy(&blk.block_size, buf+8, 2);
blk.block_size = htons(blk.block_size);

memcpy(&blk.file_system_block_count, buf+10, 4);
blk.file_system_block_count = htonl(blk.file_system_block_count);
```

This results in `blk.block_size` and `blk.file_system_block_count` correctly holding the value "512" and "6400" respectively.